# JPA throwing "multiple assignments to same column" during save operation

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, persistence, javabeans

I have a model class that references another model class and seem to be encountering an issue where the @OneToOne annotation fixes one problem but causes another. Removing it causes the inverse.

JPA throws "multiple assignments to same column" when trying to save changes to model. The generated SQL has duplicate columns and I'm not sure why.

Here's a preview of what the classes look like:

The parent class references look like this:

```
public class Appliance {
    public Integer locationId;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne
    public Location location;
}
```

The child Location class has an id field and a few other text fields -- very simple:

```
public class Location {
public Integer id;
public String name;
}
```

When I attempt to perform a save operation, does anyone know why JPA is creating an insert statement for the Appliance table that contains two fields named "location_id"?

I need to annotate the reference to the child class with @OneToOne if I want to be able to retrieve data from the corresponding database table to display on screen. However, If I remove @OneToOne, the save works fine, but it obviously won't load the Location data into the child object when I query the db.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you did not define an @InheritanceType on the parent Class.  Since you did not, the default is to combine the the parent and the child class into the same Table in the Single Table Strategy.

Since both entities are going into the same table, I think that @OneToOne is trying to write the id twice - regardless of which side it is on.

If you want the parent to be persisted in its own table, look at InheritanceType.JOINED.
Or consider re-factoring so that you are not persisting the parent separately as JOINED is not considered a safe option with some JPA providers.

See official Oracle Documentation below.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro002.htm#BNBQR

**37.2.4.1 The Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy**
With this strategy, which corresponds to the default InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, all classes in the hierarchy are mapped to a single table in the database. This table has a discriminator column containing a value that identifies the subclass to which the instance represented by the row belongs.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check those out tomorrow morning. I'm well versed in Java and SQL, but JPA is something that's completely new to me. :)

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't work either. I tried JOINED and SINGLE_TABLE, but it throws an error saying it can't find the dtype column.

JPA assumes I have a descriptorType column in my database and this isn't the case.

Comment: I took this a step further and added dtype columns to the database. I've tried all of your suggestions and even with them implemented, I still get "multiple assignments to same column 'location_id'".

I'm going to continue hacking away, but any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenJPA, according to the docs (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_field.html), section 8.4, the foreign key column in a one-to-one mapping:

> Defaults to the relation field name, plus an underscore, plus the name
>   of the referenced primary key column.

And the JPA API seems to concur with this (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)

I believe this means that in a one-to-one mapping, the default column name for properties in a dependent class is parentClassFieldName_dependentClassFieldName (or location_id in your case).  If that's the case, the location_id column you are defining in your Appliance class is conflicting with the location_id default column name which would be generated for your Location class.

You should be able to correct this by using the @Column(name="someColumnName") annotation and the @JoinColumn annotation on your @OneToOne relationship to force the column name to be something unique.

Comment: I actually tried this, but it didn't rectify the situation -- i still got the same error message. I'm going to try MorganR's suggestion below and see if that resolve it. I'll let you know either way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok gang, I figured it out.

Here's what the new code looks like, followed by a brief explanation...

Parent Class:

```
public class Appliance {
    public Integer locationId;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Location location;
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class Location {
public Integer id;
public String name;
}
```

The first part of the puzzle was the explicit addition of "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" in the parent class. This resolved the initial "multiple assignments to same column" by allowing the child object to be persisted.

However, I encountered an issue during update operations which is due to some sort of conflict between EBean and JPA whereby it triggers a save() operation on nested child objects rather than a cascading update() operation. I got around this by issuing an explicit update on the child object and then setting it to null before the parent update operation occurred. It's sort of a hack, but it seems like all these persistence frameworks solve one set of problems but cause others -- I guess that's why I've been old school and always rolled my own persistence code until now.